# Uploading a library to maven server

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am assigned a task of building a project using gradle and maven. The project consists of a main module and its supporting modules.

The supporting modules must be uploaded to artifact local maven repository as libraries and the main module will access them from there.

How do I upload the modules? How do I convert them to libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your build.gradle of library/module

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

artifacts {
//put library path
archives file: file('build/aar/library.aar')
}

// Define maven repository path
def localRepoPath = "file://D:/m2repo"

uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer
        {
            repository(url: localRepoPath)
             pom.artifactId = "your_artifact_id"
             pom.groupId = 'com.your.groupid'
             pom.version = android.defaultConfig.versionName

        }
}
```

Run `gradlew uploadArchives` to deploy to local maven repo.